# jupyter notebook is not launching

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

i have installed anaconda on my win 10 machine but jupyter notebook is not launching neither from `Anaconda Prompt` or `Anaconda Navigator`

when i execute `jupyter notebook` there is no output in Anaconda Prompt

[image]

and

when i click on jupyter notebook launch button in the Navigator it says `launching notebook` but nothing happen after that

`conda info` :

```
 active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\Zoubi\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Zoubi\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Zoubi\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\Zoubi\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Zoubi\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Zoubi\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Zoubi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Zoubi\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Zoubi\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Zoubi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17133
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`jupyter kernelspec list` :

```
Available kernels:
  python3    C:\Users\Zoubi\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

Any Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally fix it , the solution for me was to restore my windows 10 to previous restore point and reinstall Anaconda but this time `for all users`

Answer (score 1):

The issue have had happen to me a long dime ago. Don't know how to address the problem appropriately, but back then I've created new environment and downloaded jupyter notebook on it. Sure, the problem worth investigating, but I suppose you're in need of a fast solution.

That's how you can create new environment:

[image]